# FCM UNNotificationServiceExtension not working

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4

I have created a Target for  **UNNotificationServiceExtension** for editing notification title.

Now if I work using **Pusher** Using **APNS** My notification title changes and it's works Properly.

```
{"aps":{"alert":"push Notification","badge":1,"sound":"default","mutable-content":1}}
```

This is what I Sent through APNS.

But I am not finding the solution for FCM what should U send the Data and how it will works

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
}
```

Comment: It should be mutable_content for FCM.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too and modifying the payload helped me.

```
{"aps":{"alert":"push Notification","badge":1,"sound":"default","mutable_content":true}}
```

For more details, go through this [link](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/70#issuecomment-280182095)